# How to get an Epson-AL-CX11 printer working?

Tags: printing, epson

I have an EPSON(AL-CX11) printer that used to work with Linux, but at some point, at a Linux kernel version, it stopped working.

I can install the printer without errors, but when sending a test page, it doesn't print.
As if it never receives the printing assignment.

**Question**:  How can I get my EPSON-AL-CX11 to work with Ubuntu.

Comment: Doesn't work for me anymore. Installation successful, printing testpage status "successful" but not page print at all. 13.10/64 bit here. I am very very disappointed by Ubuntu. :-( PS I don't even know how to debug such a problem. No best practice tutorial found.
PPS The good news: xsane via network works now. Whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

### Install Epson AL-CX11 Printer Driver

1. Go to [Epson Download Center](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX)
2. Search for **AL-CX11**.
3. Download the Source file for **AcuLaser CX11 for CUPS** : **Epson-ALCX11-filter-1.1.tar.gz**
4. Install required dependencies and build environment:

   `sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev build-essential libstdc++5 bc`
5. in the terminal cd to the directory where you downloaded the tar file and type this:

   `tar -zxvf Epson-ALCX11-filter-1.1.tar.gz`

   `cd Epson-ALCX11-filter-1.1`

   `sudo ./configure`

   `sudo make install`
6. Now the driver is installed and you can simply add the printer using the **System > Administration > Printing** menu.
7. Your printer should show up in the list when you click **add new printer** button. **Select it and just click forward**
8. The recommended driver is already selected so **click forward and finish** adding the printer.
9. You may get an error about pstoalcx11.sh not installed, don’t worry.
   Now copy the files alcx11, alcx11_lprwrapper.sh  and pstoalcx11.sh from /usr/local/bin to /usr/lib/cups/filter:

   `sudo cp /usr/local/bin/*cx11* /usr/lib/cups/filter/`
10. Print a test page, **It Works!**

Comment: As Fedora 23 user I just had to install the both rpm packages (filter and filter cups) from the Epson driver page and execute the following selinux command: `setsebool -P cups_execmem 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Run following command to find out missing libraries afterwards.

```
/usr/local/bin/pstoalcx11.sh PageSize=A4 XY600=5100×6600 MediaType=normal TonerSave=false InputSlot=cassette1 Collate=on Copies=1 Color=color Resolution=600dpi XY600=5100×6600
```

I had 64 bit system, needed to install 32 bit libraries to get it working.

How to install 32 bit libraries see following answer I just replaced `libstdc++6:i386` with `libstdc++5:i386` here:

[How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit/454254#454254)