# How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and the current Android development SDK, which contains 32-bit executables. I found that I cannot run those 32-bit binaries. Trying to start them from bash gives me an error:

```
$ ./adb
bash: ./adb: No such file or directory
```

It is there though:

```
$ ls -al ./adb
-rwxrwxrwx 1 thomas thomas 1231255 Jan 17 13:31 ./adb
$ file ./adb
./adb: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, not stripped.
```

Same symptom for all the other 32-bit tools in the Android SDK.

In olden days one could just install 32-bit libraries on 64-bit Ubuntu to get 32-bit support, but that does not seem to work anymore.

How do I run 32-bit apps on a 64-bit Ubuntu distribution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19524010/1778421

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270351/how-to-compile-32-bit-executable-on-64-bit-system

Comment: Relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/352783/43390

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/a/905083/173666

Answer (score 251, accepted):

To run a 32-bit executable file on a 64-bit multi-architecture Ubuntu system, you have to add the `i386` architecture and install the three library packages `libc6:i386`, `libncurses5:i386`, and `libstdc++6:i386`:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Or if you are using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) or below, use this:

```sh
echo "foreign-architecture i386" > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

If fails, do also

```
sudo apt-get install multiarch-support
```

After these steps, you should be able to run the 32-bit application:

```
./example32bitprogram
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj This helped me out! However, what is the last command "sudo ./adb" supposed to do actually?

Comment: It executes the 32bit adb binary file which was present in the current directory.

Comment: to get aapt working on Ubuntu 14.04, I had to install `lib32z1` as well, but noticed it pulled in libc6-i386 (distinction, notice the hyphen, not the colon).

Comment: I did your steps, `libc6:i386`, `libncurses5:i386`, `libstdc++6:i386` are newest version and set to manually installed. But after that it says: "`Soma packages could not be installed.This may mean you have requested impossible situation or you are using unstable distribution ...`" and unmet dependancies: `libstdc++6-4.4-dev:i386` depends `g++-4.4:i386`(wont be installed). conflicts: `libstdc++6-4.4-dbg:i386` ... and other conflicts about `libstdc++6-4.4/6/7` etc.  What is wrong or should i leave it as it is now?

Comment: @FredrickGauss get into [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company).

Comment: I couldn't get into there but for now it seems working, thanks.

Comment: I know it is an Ubuntu Q&A, but in case anyone heads here (as did I), that procedure worked on Debian Stretch 9.0 x64 too

Comment: Totally stuck exactly like @FredrickGauss after a fresh Ubuntu 14.04.6 install. `libstdc++6:i386` is blocked with dependency after blocking dependency after blocking dependency etc. Switching to a 32-bit install.

Comment: @FredrickGauss  only libstdc++6:i386 has conflicts, I install the other package, it works

Comment: is it normal that after i sudo apt-add-architecture i386 and i sudo apt update, my ubuntu 18.06 boots into a tty?

Answer (score 12):

"No such file or directory" may appaear when you have your binary, but it lacks some libraries. If you install `build-essential` package, you will have `ldd` command available. This command `ldd ./adb | grep not` will show you what libraries are missing. Just install these libraries in i386 arch with apt. Like this: `apt-get install libmissing:i386`
Beware, some buggy packages will try to delete 64bit version firs.

Comment: Thank you, that would explain the weird error message. 

I was first confused why bash would give me this error (instead of some error coming more clearly from the child process which misses the libraries), but now I guess bash just sees exec(3) returning ENOENT and prints this out.

Answer (score 9):

Additionally to the excellent answer of Zanna and Avinash Raj I had to install gcc-multilib as well:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

Possibly this is because I wanted to run an old gcc version on 64bit.

Answer (score 5):

And if you want to use "adb" there is a package for it:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

And about 32-bit libraries - only:

```
sudo apt-add-architecture i386
```

will be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I wanted to use the android tools downloaded from google, not the ones in the Ubuntu repos. I am also not sure about the completeness of that package.

Comment: Ubuntu repositories must have the new version. The package contains only adb. If you want fastboot - there is package for it too :)

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to Zanna:
The following has solved the android studio problem of "unable to install libraries":

```
sudo apt-get install libdb1-compact tzdata initscripts
```

This replaces missing library libstdc++6-i386 which is probably because the package has been obsoleted. Not sure why this specific library was important.