# installing 32 bit libraries on ubuntu 14.04 64bit:errors

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32stdc++6 : Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

what do i do now?

Comment: Is multiarch actavted on your system? What is `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` saying?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`sudo apt-get -f install`
This should install any missing dependencies in your system.
If you are trying to install a package, you can also try adding `--fix-missing` to your installation command.