# How can I install Yousician Launcher?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I've just downloaded a file called "Yousician.tar.gz". I understand it's a compacted file and it contains other files and folders. I can extract the contents with no problems. I wonder, though, how I can run the software. I really have no experience with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (which is the one installed in my PC) or any other version of it.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! File archives can contain about everything, even other archives. So without knowing what's in the archive, we can't tell you what to do with it. But usually a readme file is included, explaining what to do.

Answer (score 3):

1. Download archive from https://app.yousician.com/signup
2. Unpack it to any folder
3. Go to this folder
4. Run “Yousician Launcher” file

Tip: if your OS version is 64 bit, run this command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386 libglu1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libxrandr2:i386
```

You may also find this article helpful: [How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit)?

Answer (score 3):

**Using Yousician on Linux is not longer possible.**

They seem to withdraw Linux support lately.

There is declined [feature request](https://yousician.uservoice.com/forums/296820-feature-requests/suggestions/34498729-bring-back-linux-support-or-at-least-make-it-com) about this.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a supplement to Andrew's answer as I followed a different route for my install.

Do the following in a terminal window.

1. `cd` to the Download folder.
2. Extract the archive using `tar -xvf Yousician.tar.gz`
3. Next we will move it to `/opt` using `sudo mv Yousician\ Launcher/ /opt/yousician`
4. And make a shortcut to the launcher using `sudo ln -sf /opt/yousician/Yousician\ Launcher /usr/bin/yousician`
5. We also want a Unity dash entry so run `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/Yousician.desktop`, then paste the following

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Yousician
   Comment=Start the Yousician Launcher
   Exec="yousician"
   Icon=/opt/yousician/Yousician.app/Yousician_Data/Resources/UnityPlayer.png
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Categories=Game;
   Name[en]=Yousician
   ```

And that is it. You should now find it in the Unity Dash (might need a restart).

PS. for a 64-bit check the tip in Andrew's answer (based on the [official guide](https://yousician.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202168922-Installing-Yousician-Mac-PC-Linux-)).