# Using x32 Program on x64 Architecture Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, package-management, 64-bit, 32-bit, realtek-wireless

So I'm trying to get my Realtek RTL8812AU USB Wireless to work. I came across this package for it: https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au

I'm about to install it, but it says it's built for x86 and I am running Ubuntu 15.10 x64. I looked for CONFIG_PLATFORM for x64 architecture in the Makefile and I couldn't find any (but, as my name suggests, i'm a newb).

So, I set about trying to install i386 libraries. And this forum: 
[How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit)
Told me to do the following:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Using aptitude I saw a lot of dependencies and conflicts with these packages... should I be doing this? Are these old packages?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply try to go with the instructions in the Readme file of the github repo...

First... install git

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Clone the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au
cd rtl8812au
```

compile the module...

```
make
sudo cp 8812au.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless
sudo depmod
sudo insmod 8812au.ko
```

If you get an error, you might need the kernel headers...

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Start again with 'make'...

You don't need the i386 libraries to compile a kernel module.

Comment: Awesome! It worked! The only thing is when I connect to the internet it says "You are now connected to the wi-fi network: '(none)' " and then it doesn't show the signal strength. Not a huge problem, but any ideas why?

Comment: Try to dig the issues page [here](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au/issues) for some solution. There might be a solution

Comment: By the way... If the module is not loaded at boot, just ad **8812au** to the file **/etc/modules**