# How to install Vmware 32 bit on Ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, vmware, 32-bit

I tried this [How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit) but still got

```
This is a x86 bundle and does not match that of the 
current architecture.  Please download the x64 bundle.
```

I want to install the file called `VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.6-2700073.i386.bundle`. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> 'This is a x86 bundle and does not match that of the current architecture. Please download the x64 bundle.'

That message seems valid to me.

> I want to install the file called 'VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.6-2700073.i386.bundle'.

No, you do not. You are making a mistake here. You do not install a 32-bit VMWare bundle in a 64-bit system.

You need to install 64-bit VMWare bundle in your 64-bit system. Inside a 64-bit VMWare you can then install different operating systems that can be 32-bit.

Comment: Explain the downvote please? AFAIK this is correct so please explain what mistake I made?