# unable to enable i386 architecture on ubuntu12.04 LTS

Tags: wine, 32-bit

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I tried installing wine and the following command does not work and I guess it stops the other required commands from working too.

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

It says the option "--add-architecture" is not valid.

"dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture"

The other commands being:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install wine

The last command ends with an error saying the required dependencies are not met and couldn't be fixed either. Please help.

Thanks !

Comment: please post the output of the following commands **uname -a** and **lsb_release -a**

Comment: There is an alternative method for 12.04: see [How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?](http://askubuntu.com/a/454254/178692)

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case  I recommend you to run the following to manually add the 32 bit support assuming you are using 64 bit ubuntu.

Become privileged user

```
sudo su
```

Add 32 bit support

```
echo "foreign-architecture i386" > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
```

Install 32 bit dependency packages you need to install libc , since its ubuntu 12.04

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```