# brother ql570 labelprinter driver does not work

Tags: drivers, 16.04

My labelprinter brother ql570 always worked for me on Ubuntu, but not since i upgraded to 16.04.
I used the internal driver ql550 recommended by ubuntu and the drivers from brother.com website
The internal driver ql550 gave red blinking Light when printing.
The drivers on the brother website are 32bit. Can that be a problem on 64bit ubuntu?

Is there a way to get the printer working on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

- The drivers you get from brother are 32 bit drivers
- So you have to provide an 32bit environment (especially the libraries) for them.

First, make sure you have multiarch support enabled on your 16.04 -- normally you shoud get the following:

```
# dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
# dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
```

If the i386 Part is missing, have a look an this post:
[How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit)

Then install the 32bit libraries:

```
apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Now, the brother printer should work again.