# How to install Firefox 32-bit ESR 52 without uninstalling Firefox 64-bit on 16.04

Tags: firefox, java

My computer has Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS 64-bit and Firefox 52 64-bit.

For one of the government web sites, because it is using browser Java plugin to sign documents, I need to install:

1. **Firefox ESR 52**. Ordinary Firefox 52 does not support Java as browser plugin anymore, because NPAPI was removed ([source](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/)).
2. **Firefox ESR 52 32-bit**. I know for sure Firefox 32-bit only supports Sun Java on Windows, but not sure if this is also a limitation on Ubuntu. If it is, I need Firefox 32-bit version and not Firefox 64-bit version. [2](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/)

I know I can install Firefox 32-bit like using:

1. install Firefox 32-bit in terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt install firefox:i386
   ```

   but installing Firefox 32-bit will uninstall Firefox 64-bit, which I would like to keep.
2. download and extract Firefox 52 ESR 32-bit from [2](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/).

Is there any other was to install Firefox ESR 52 32-bit and also install Sun Java 32-bit on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS 64-bit without uninstalling Firefox 52 64-bit?

See:

1. [Plug-in support has been dropped other than Flash](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2016/plug-in-support-has-been-dropped-other-than-flash/)
2. [Download Firefox Extended Support Release](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/)

Thanks

Comment: If you do not want to use apt, or download it, then you would have to compile from source. What is wrong with downloading and extracting ?

Comment: It is not so simple. When downloading and extracting Firefox 32-bit it does not work on 64-bit linux. Optimal way it would be installing just some 32-bit libraries instead of installing Firefox 32-bit from repository. Do you know which of the packages (32-bit libraries) should be installed.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit

Answer (score 8):

Please try this workaround. For me, the **plugins** like **Java** and VLC came back after doing this. I'm using **Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit** with **Mozilla Firefox 64 bit version 52** (not ESR) and **Java JDK 1.8.0_112**

1. Open **Firefox** and type **about:config** in address bar and press enter
2. Click '**I accept the risk!**'
3. Right click anywhere and select **New>Boolean**
4. Type **plugin.load_flash_only** in the box that appears
5. Set the value to **false**
6. Clear all **history** and **restart** Firefox

I'm also using various Government websites which uses java plugin and Digital Signatures.

Try this and let me know.

**Edit**: Mozilla Firefox 53 will remove the flag `plugin.load_flash_only` so that this workaround won't work anymore.

**Pale Moon** web browser team announced that they will continue the support of **NPAPI plugins** indefinitely. To install java plugin in Pale Moon, run this in terminal

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```

I've tested java plugin in Pale Moon browser. 100% working.

Comment: Worked for me, for Juniper VPN which uses the Java plugin.

Comment: Yes this worked for me as well, thanks very much for posting these steps. Didn't have to downgrade to 32-bit or ESR.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a temporary workaround until Firefox 53 comes out when that flag will be removed.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: there is no plugin.load* property. There are various other plugin.* ones; but not this one.

Comment: Hi, GhostCat

You have to add the property, if you don't have one. See the 3rd step I wrote. Cheers.

Comment: This workaround will stop working from Firefox version 53, which will be out soon. Either there will be another workaround in 53, or we have to find a reliable web browser with updates as well as NPAPI plugin support

Comment: With Firefox 53 it is still working for me.

Answer (score 3):

I use 16.04 LTS 64-bit
I download and unpack 64-bit Firefox (but older version - v.45) from here https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/
And after that I close my 'standard' previously installed Firefox and run 'firefox' file from extracted folder of version 45 archive.
So I open my site and successfully run Java application inside it.

P.S.
I also updated Java to have the latest version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

You could install a new version in a local folder (such as `~/applications/firefox_esr/`), but you won't be able to run them simultaneously. From what I've read on [Firefox website](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Problems-with-add-ons-plugins-or/Why-do-Java-Silverlight-Adobe-Acrobat-and-other-plugins-no/ta-p/31069), the Linux version does not have the same limitation the Windows version has; so you better just use the ESR 64-bits.

---

I had a similar issue but the above wasn't enough to solve the problem with the Java plugin. If that is not getting you through, install [SeaMonkey 2.46 (64-bits)](https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/seamonkey/releases/2.46/contrib/seamonkey-2.46.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2) and try again.

Comment: NPAPI plugin support will be removed from the next ESR version. So we better find another solution. I will try SeaMonkey.