# How to change java version for Firefox ESR 52?

Tags: 16.04, firefox, java

I "installed" FF52 esr this morning, in order to still be able to use java within the browser (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894871/how-to-install-firefox-52-esr-on-16-04)).

Works fine; but FF uses an older version of Java; it tells me it is using Java 1.7.

But when I do a simply `java -version` command line, I am told that I have Java 1.8 there.

So how exactly do I control which Java version is "plugged in"?

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing: I knew this procedure earlier on; but I thought at some point it would be no longer working. But it is still super simple:

- stop firefox
- cd into ~/.mozilla
- mkdir plugins
- cd plugins
- ln -s /from/whatever/java/installation/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so

That's it. You fire up firefox again; and *that* version of java should be used.

Nicely documented by Oracle, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_plugin.html) or [there](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/manual-plugin-install-linux-136395.html).