# Install Java Plugin in Pale Moon Browser

Tags: java, 64-bit, plugins, palemoon

**Pale Moon** seems to continue supporting **NPAPI plugins** like **Java** indefinitely. I use a website, which require java plugin enabled. But I can't get the java plugin in the plugins list. I know the symbolic link method for Firefox. How to install the plugin in Pale Moon? I'm on **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit**, **Java JDK 8u121** and **Pale Moon 64 bit**

**Edit1**: After 3 years of asking this question, Java plugin still works fine in **Palemoon v28.9.2-1 64 bit** on **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**. Java version is **JRE 8u251 64 bit**

**Edit2:** As of 20th October 2020, Oracle completely removed Java Plugin from 8u271 JRE and JDK packages mentioned in [this](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u271-relnotes.html) article. But 8u261 or prior versions works just fine.

Comment: Is there a .so file (or a symlink to it) in the `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins` folder?

Comment: No, there is no .so file associated with java in that directory. but I've created a symbolic link for the file `libnpjp2.so` in the directory `/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/`. Shall I create a link for the same file to the directory `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins` ?

Comment: May be worth a try. (I'm really not sure.)

Comment: Now you can be 100% sure. It worked. OMG I'm so glad you helped me. Thank You.

Comment: Great! :) Then can you please post the solution as an answer. I think quite a few people will encounter the same problem.

Comment: Yes. I really do think so. Posted as answer. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As **Gunnar Hjalmarsson** said,

To install **java plugin** in **Pale Moon** web browser, you have to create a **symbolic link** of the file `libnpjp2.so` to the directory `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`

Here goes the exact terminal command

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```

If needed, make corresponding changes to the command, if your java version and/or system architecture is different.

**Note**: Install latest Java JRE/JDK properly before adding symbolic link.

I have verified that the java plugin is working, by going to [this](https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp) page.

[image: I have verified that the java plugin is working]

Comment: Odd, PaleMoon 27.3 64bit on 16.04, with Java 1.7 installed, just works! It appears /etc/alternatives is used.

`root@brix:/tmp# ls -la /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so -> /etc/alternatives/mozilla-javaplugin.so`

`root@brix:/tmp# ls -la /etc/alternatives/mozilla-javaplugin.so
/etc/alternatives/mozilla-javaplugin.so -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so`

Comment: hi kevinf, Java plugin is not working in Pale Moon 27.3.0 64 bit. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit and Oracle JDK 1.8.0_131 64 bit. I'm not sure how do I link the java plugin to Pale Moon. In plugins list Java plugin is there, but Java plugin is not working as expected. Your code is a bit confusing, can you explain it a bit further? I already have the plugin file libnpjp2.so in /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/ and in /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/ and also in /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/amd64/. please help

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by not working as expected my instructions were to create the links which you seemingly have

Comment: @kevinf
I tried to verify Java with [this](https://www.java.com/verify) link. The Java applet in java verification  page is not loading, which implies Java plugin is not working. In previous Pale Moon version 27.2.1, I created a link using the code `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so`. The link is still there, and Java plugin is there in the plugins list, but now Java is not working. So, my question is that, how can I create a link in my system ,inorder to get Java working again. I use Oracle JDK 8u131 64 bit.

Comment: Sorry, I no longer have that test environment / pale moon install. Best of luck :) If the destination of that symlink still exists, then I don't know what to check next.

Comment: Status: Pale Moon 31.3.1 with Oracle JDK 8u261 (still available for download from Oracle), Java Applets still working, thanks!