# GCC - Compile 32-bit code on 64-bit system

Tags: 64-bit, compiling, 32-bit, gcc

I'm studying Assembly and I need to compile a piece of C code into a 32-bit executable file. The issue is that I keep getting this error. I've tried installing gcc-multilib and g++-lib, but it hasn't helped. Anyone know what might be going on?

```
> gcc main.s -m32 -o main

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Using gcc version 4.8.5 (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu4) on Ubuntu 16.10.

Update: Added the compilation command. I compiled the .s file beforehand using `gcc -m32 -S main.c` because I needed to have a look at the Assembly code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact command you are using to compile the code - not just the error message

Comment: Well I suspect that `gcc-multilib` only installs the 32-bit components for the *default* `gcc` (i.e. `gcc-6` on 16.10) - have you tried installing the corresponding `gcc-4.8-multilib`?

Comment: Relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/352783/43390

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/a/454254/173666

Answer (score 7):

The `gcc-multilib` package only provides 32-bit support for the current default compiler.

Since you are using a non-default compiler (`gcc-4.8` versus the system's default `gcc-6`) you will need to install the underlying version-specific multilib package explicitly e.g.

```
sudo apt install gcc-4.8-multilib
```

(or the equivalent from your favorite package manager).

Comment: Hello, I am trying to use gcc-9.3.0 to build 32-bit code. But `sudo apt install gcc-9-multilib` `g++-9-multilib` does not work, meaning the compiler still tries to build 64-bit code. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @r0ng can you be more specific than "doesn't work"? What happens, exactly? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I found the problem I added `-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9` in the make file, but forgot to remove it after I installed  `gcc-9-multilib`.