# Cross Compiling with Linaro 7.1.1 arm-linux-gnueabihf

Tags: kernel, compiling, arm, beagleboard, linaro

How can I properly download the linaro toolchain and set it up so that I can use it with the kernel Makefile? When I test my version on the `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --version` function it works but when compiling a custom kernel it fails.

---

**Context**

I am working to compile a custom linux kernel for the Beaglebone Black board. The guide I am following to build the custom kernel is [here](https://embedjournal.com/kernel-compilation-beaglebone-black/).

While following the steps for the guide, I need to use `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`
in order to cross compile the kernel for the Beaglebone hardware. So I have installed [linaro's toolchain from their website](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/arm-linux-gnueabi/). I just downloaded it and then unpacked it to the `/opt/` folder.

```
$ cd /opt/
$ sudo mv gcc-linaro-7.1.1-2017.08-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi.tar.xz/ gcc-arm-linux
$ export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gcc-arm-linux/bin
```

I test and make sure that things worked in installing.

$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --version

And my output looks like the following image:

[image: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc version]

Once I'm finished with that I am compiling the kernel using the standard Makefile.

```
$ cd ~/linux
$ sudo make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- bb.org_defconfig
$ sudo make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- uImage dtbs LOADADDR=0x80008000 -j4
```

At this point I run into errors on the command to actually compile the kernel.

```
Makefile:686: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler
make: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: Command not found
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CC      scripts/mod/empty.o
/bin/sh: 1: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: not found
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target 'scripts/mod/empty.o' failed
make[2]: *** [scripts/mod/empty.o] Error 127
scripts/Makefile.build:403: recipe for target 'scripts/mod' failed
make[1]: *** [scripts/mod] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:556: recipe for target 'scripts' failed
make: *** [scripts] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

What is most confusing is that the errors indicate that `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: not found`, however I can run the command `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --version` in the same folder and it will execute properly.

The solution to this problem could be to just install it using apt:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm*
```

Which is suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180185/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi-command-not-found) response, but that doesn't resolve my confusion.

Why can I test my version on the `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` function but it doesn't execute in the Makefile properly? How can I properly download the linaro toolchain and set it up so that I can use it with the kernel Makefile?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same problem as me, but I came accross this post when looking for an answer to my own issue.

I ran into similar issue when using an older linux-arm cross compiler from inside a docker container. The issue was the cross compile gcc binary was 32-bit, and the container running make was 64-bit. The make script was reporting "arm-linux/gcc not found"

You can check if it is 32-bit by doing

```
file absolute-path-to-gcc
```

for example

```
root@b61b0b938b8a:~# file /usr/local/arm-linux/bin/gcc
/usr/local/arm-linux/bin/gcc: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped
```

To fix this I had to add `i386` to the docker container, as in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit) question

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```