# Trying to run 32bit application on 64bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, compatibility

Just to clarify: I've look up to each existing question with accepted answers, but these questions were asked before Ubuntu 16.04 LTS came out and these answers are no longer working. Tried everything from said commands, but I still can't run 32bit applications.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit. All said libraries are installed, but I still can't get the 32bit applicaton work. This is terminal dump:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Google doesn't help much and as I said, each question that already have an accepted answer just has outdated informations that are no longer supported or I don't know why it doesn't work, it just doesn't. I've got a little bit upset and will accept ANY working answer.

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. I've looked into this question and the answers do not work. I can't get it work, it still is missing that damn library...

Comment: Did you also check https://askubuntu.com/a/454300/158442 and install the corresponding package that provides `libX11.so.6`?

Comment: Okay, it works, thanks :) I've finally installed missing libraries using the `dpkg -S libfile` command. Sound from the application doesn't work, but that's a topic for another forum. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, thanks to @muru's answer linked me to [related question's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/482/783091), I've managed to get my 32bit application working on Ubuntu 64bit.

What I needed was `dpkg -S missing-lib-file.so` command to find out package containing the missing library, and `apt-get install package-name:i386` command to install 32bit compatible package containing the missing library.

Thread can be closed.