# error libgtk-3.so.0 not installed even though it's in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Tags: software-installation, shared-library

I'm trying to install a CAN [emulator](http://www.dthoughts.com/products/canmate.html) software with GTK and I keep getting an error.

> **CANMate**: error while loading shared libraries: **libgtk-3.so.0**: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

But when `apt` says libgtk-3 is installed:

```
$ sudo apt install libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgtk-3-0 is already the newest version (3.22.30-1ubuntu1).
libgtk-3-dev is already the newest version (3.22.30-1ubuntu1).
```

And the shared lib can be found inside `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

```
$ ls | grep libgtk-3
libgtk-3-0
libgtk-3.so
libgtk-3.so.0
libgtk-3.so.0.2200.30
```

I think the installation file `CANMatev1.3.deb` is failing to locate the shared `lib` while installation.

Can you please, help me resolve this error?

Comment: try re-creating your dynamically linked list of run-time libraries cache  with `sudo ldconfig`.   The [list of] directories aren't searched, only the cache is.

Comment: @guiverc I tried `sudo ldconfig` and tried reinstalling `sudo dpkg -i <deb.name>`. But when I try calling program after the installation, it still says `libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file`

Comment: Although package information (via `dpkg -i`) shows the architecture as "all", the actual `CANMate` application appears to be a 32-bit binary - hence you will likely need to enable multiarch and install the `libgtk-3-0:i386` package

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you! It worked. How did you know it was a x32 arch? Would like to know so that I can check the next time something similar happens.

Comment: @clmno please see below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a hunch, let's see if the problem is that the application is 32-bit

- unpack the deb to a local directory

  ```
  $ mkdir ./tmproot
  $ dpkg -x CANMAte_V1.3_Linux/deb/CANMatev1.3.deb ./tmproot
  ```
- examine the application binary

  ```
  $ file ./tmproot/usr/bin/CANMate 
  ./tmproot/usr/bin/CANMate: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=061c53b0a1b07aca998506681c2a93039181979e, not stripped
  ```

So, since you are using a 64-bit OS, you will need to enable multiarch and install the 32-bit version of any required libraries

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgtk-3-0:i386
```

See also [How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit)