# Can I install Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit on Intel64 (IA-64)

Tags: 18.04, 64-bit, intel-atom

I currently have a netbook with Intel Atom N550 CPU. For the longest time I had been using 32-bit OS's on this PC, until I recently found out that apparently this CPU supports 64-bit. 
Checking at Intel's [site about this CPU's Spec](https://ark.intel.com/products/50154/Intel-Atom-Processor-N550-1M-Cache-1-50-GHz-), it supports Intel® 64, and with the help of few checker I confirmed it does supports it.
But I have seen that some sites says AMD64 is not same as Intel64 and the latest Ubuntu LTS 18.04 only has AMD64 iso. So can I install that AMD64 on Intel64?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official [Intel Atom Processor N550 (1M Cache, 1.50 GHz Product Specifications- Intel ARK](https://web.archive.org/web/20200108235207/https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/50154/intel-atom-processor-n550-1m-cache-1-50-ghz.html) webpage, the Intel Atom N550 has a 64-bit instruction set, so the Ubuntu 18.04 amd64 .iso file is compatible with this processor. Ubuntu 18.04 does not have a 32-bit .iso file, so the Ubuntu 18.04 amd64 .iso file is the correct .iso file to install.

In general `i386` in a file name means that it is is compatible with Intel 32-bit processors and `amd64` is compatible with both Intel 64-bit processors and AMD 64-bit processors. As far as 32-bit vs. 64-bit operating systems are concerned `i386` packages are compatible with 32-bit operating systems and `amd64` packages are compatible with 64-bit operating systems.

Comment: Also, I have heard that it doesn't has backward compatibility, is that true? can I run 32-bit programs on ubuntu with my current CPU?

Comment: [How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/)