# Can I dual boot lubuntu 21.10 and windows 7 64 bit,32 bit

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, windows, hp

I am currently running windows 7 32 bit on HP Mini 200 4301tu with intel atom n2600 processor, 2 gb ram.

My first question is, Is my cpu x64? as on the command `echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` returns `x86`

According to Performance Information and Tools my pc is `64 bit` capable.

My second question is, can i dual boot lubuntu 21.10 and windows 7 32 bit?

thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I install Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit on Intel64 (IA-64)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1105058/)

Comment: FYI:  32bit windows is often found on lower-end devices as it was $5 cheaper from microsoft than the 64bit version.  Consumers understood $5 a lot more than 32 vs 64 bit.  Many commands tell you the architecture of the OS you're running; not what the hardware is capable of.

Comment: I have re-installed windows 7 several times,  but everytime  i run ```Performance Information and Tools```, it says that my pc is not ```64 bit``` capable. But this time it shows it is capable os ```64-bit```. can you explain me that ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through your questions individually:

**Q. Is my cpu x64?**

Yes. [Intel reports the Atom N2600 is a 64-bit CPU](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/58916/intel-atom-processor-n2600-1m-cache-1-6-ghz.html).

**Q. Can I dual-boot Lubuntu 21.10 and windows 7 32 bit?**

Yes. The minimum system requirements for Lubuntu are difficult to find and will vary wildly based on what you plan on doing with the OS, but a basic installation of 20.04 will consume about 340MB of RAM. 21.10 will likely be somewhere close to that number as well.

What you may want to do is first boot into a Live Session to see how well the OS runs on your computer. If it's all good, then use the Installer to set up a dual-boot environment. If it's not quite what you're looking for, consider trying one of the other light-weight Ubuntu flavours, such as [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org) or [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org).

Comment: The Windows 7 installation is said to be the 32-bit version, which means that it will return x86 regardless of what the CPU is capable of. The Intel site clearly states it's a 64-bit CPU, and I would trust Intel over Microsoft any day of the week 