# Unable to execute binary, unexpected "not found in PATH" error

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm trying to execute a binary from [this cross-compiler toolchain](https://uclibc.org/downloads/binaries/0.9.30.1/cross-compiler-armv4l.tar.bz2) (link to .tar.bz2 file).

When I try to run the binary, I get a surprising message about the file not being in my `$PATH`, even though it exists, and is executable:

```
$ cross-compiler-armv4l/bin/armv4l-gcc
can't find cross-compiler-armv4l/bin/armv4l-gcc in $PATH

$ ls -l cross-compiler-armv4l/bin/armv4l-gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rzg rzg 31964 Apr  5  2009 cross-compiler-armv4l/bin/armv4l-gcc
```

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on x86_64, and the architecture of the file I'm running is 32-bit, so I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/454254/914766) to install the i386 libc, but it was not enough.

```
$ file cross-compiler-armv4l/bin/armv4l-gcc
cross-compiler-armv4l/bin/armv4l-gcc: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped
```

If I run `strace`, the `stat` of the file is failing:

```
access("/home/user/busybox-1.32.0/cross-compiler-armv4l/bin/armv4l-gcc", X_OK) = 0
stat("/home/user/busybox-1.32.0/cross-compiler-armv4l/bin/armv4l-gcc", 0xffe4d108) = -1 EOVERFLOW (Value too large for defined data type)
```

Comment: Can you also add what your `$PATH` includes ?

Comment: Does running the 32 bit program work if you use an absolute path (so no PATH lookup needed)?  Does running ldd on the 32 bit executable produce reasonable output, or some bogus claim of :not an executable" -- when the 32bit loader is missing.  If it runs, then you can fix your PATH by adding the location of the 32 bit executable.

Comment: `PATH` is normal (`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin` and some others) but I'm not asking the shell to search the `PATH` here. `ldd` returns nothing because it's statically linked.

Comment: what if you try running the cross compiler from whatever directory it is in with `./`