# How do I run the precompiled sqlite package on Ubuntu 18.04 without installing it?

Tags: software-installation, binary

I downloaded the [precompiled sqlite package](https://www.sqlite.org/2021/sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3350400.zip) from the [official page](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

```
$ ls -l
total 4168
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu  584260 Apr  2 23:40 sqldiff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1162244 Apr  2 23:41 sqlite3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 2516704 Apr  2 23:41 sqlite3_analyzer
```

However, running it this way doesn't work

```
./sqlite3
-bash: ./sqlite3: No such file or directory
```

`file` command gives this

```
$ file ./sqlite3
./sqlite3: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-, for GNU/Linux 4.3.0, stripped
```

`uname` command gives this

```
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

I'm running on a Ubuntu 18.04 box. What do I do?

Comment: Use the complete path to your downloaded `sqlite3`

Comment: Did you download the appropriate package for your computer's architecture? What does `file ./sqlite3` say as compared to `uname -m`?

Comment: ... in fact, it looks like it is a 32-bit binary, so if you are running a 64-bit system (likely) you will need to have the required 32-bit library support. See for example [How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit)

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has sqlite3-3.22.0 in the official repositories. Do you really absolutely need the latest version? You could simply install the one that ships with your Ubuntu: `sudo apt install sqlite3`.